# Bar chart in Excel 2010 with values over maximum

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

How can I make a chart like this in Excel 2010?

[image: bar chart with extrapolation]

Image from: [EPA.gov](http://www.epa.gov/recovery/images/bar-chart.gif)

I have data where two out of 20 values are disproportionately large. In order to create a useful chart I'd like to cut out a part of the Y axis (as shown in the chart above).

An alternative would be to limit the height of the values to the maximum†, but to add an arrow to the top. Or to let the bar fade out.

†That's what Excel 2010 does when specifying a maximum that is smaller than the largest value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no function in Excel charting to do this, but Jon Peltier has a nice article on an alternative approach... http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/broken-y-axis-in-excel-chart/

Comment: After reading this I feel stupid. It's so obvious how to let a bar fade out. Thanks!